# Spam of FCM push notifications on iOS 17 Beta

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, ios17

I have a testing app running iOS 17 Beta. And I am using a script using the following library: https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php. It works fine on iOS 16, that is, a single notification. However it sends around 11 push notifications on iOS 17 Beta.Is there anyone else having this issue? I also reported a bug on Firebase, but they are not replying. Thanks.

I tried sending notifications with the same code for IOS 16 and iOS 17 Beta

Stpes to reproduce:

1. Install iOS 17 Beta from Apple Beta downloads on an iPhone (simulators don’t handle push notifs)
2. You need to have a test app installed on the above iPhone. Xcode 15 Beta will allow you to build and run the app on the iPhone above.
3. You need to have an app on Firebase dashboard with FCM enabled. Link the iOS app and the Firebase app
4. On the php script, replace all the data for the device and FCM
5. Run it. Doesn’t matter if app is on the foreground or the background
6. A/B test it with another phone running other previous iOS version

Comment: SO is not a good resource for questions stating "it doesn't work" without a duplicatable example - we would need specific code along with troubleshooting. More importantly though, beta products are just that; beta, and attempting to troubleshoot third party libraries running on beta software is not something SO is for. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: We have the same issue with iOS 17 Beta, did you get any more information about this issue?

Comment: This does not seem to be a problem with Firebase, but one of the iOS 17 Beta. What do you intend to find out that https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/issues/814 on GitHub does not provide? Are you seeing multiple push-notifications for any service other than Firebase?

Comment: @qq4 I was seeking out other people that might have also come up with the same problem. Which they have, confirming its an Apple issue. Also, I just tested iOS 17 Beta 5 and the problem persists. This is bad.

Comment: I've created a thread on the Apple Developer forum: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/735807

Comment: The issue still persists on the iOS 17 Beta 6

Answer (score 2):

On the current latest iOS 17 Beta 7, we have fixed the issue as follows: Remove the 'id':

```
        'headers' => [
            'apns-priority' => ,
        ],
        'payload' => [
            'aps' =>
                array_merge(
                    [
                        'alert' => ,
                        'sound' => ,
                    ],
                    [
                        'id' => // Comment out this parameter 
                        'send_date' => ,
                    ],
                    $this->getPayload()
                ),
        ],
```

We have also tested on pre iOS 17 and also works.

Comment: Seems good, thank you (but still strange)

Answer (score 0):

Just rename "id" to "somethingother" in app and your PushService.
That worked for me. Apple Mods blocked this answer in their Dev-Forum two times :/